# No options for setting visibility of headers when building an iOS static library

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I am building an iOS static lib using **Xcode4.4**. But when i come to setting the visibility of headers, I can't see any options. Normally there should be some options like **Public, Private, Project**. Having compared to some other lib projects, I still can't find the problem...

The screenshot of file inspector when I chose **Hellor.h** looks like this:

[image: file inspector view of Hellor.h]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things did change since Xcode 4.4. I ask Apple Developer Technical Support for help, and here is reply:

**In the latest Xcode, exported headers are setup under the Build Phases of your target library. By default, the static library template creates a "Copy Files" phase. Any headers added to this phase will be copied to the include directory for the library and hence "made public". If your project lacks a "Copy Files" build phase, follow the instructions under "Configuring Exported Headers" in the "Creating the Library" section of the "Using Static Libraries in iOS" guide to create and configure the phase. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html**

Answer (score 0):

There are no "headers" associated with a static library - all you get is a .a file. What you want is to create a "Framework" project, which it appears is now possible for iOS projects in Xcode 4.

Comment: Thank you David. It seems to be the problem of Xcode 4.4. I try to create the same static lib under Xcode 4.3.2, then everything just works fine. As for Xcode 4.4, you mention that I should create a "Framework" project, but I can't see any option for creating an "iOS framework" in Xcode...

Comment: The problem with just a library is that where do you put the headers? If you want to distribute it, you have to put the headers and .a file in a folder, no? I'm going to guess that the reason it doesn't work in 4.4 is that Apple is pushing you to use a "Framework". I'm going to guess there is a thread on that on SO but haven't looked myself. I found out you COULD do a framework now when I incorrectly told someone a month or so ago you couldn't do it, and I know one project I use now, DTCoreText, has a framework that can be created.